# Javascript Confirm box cancel functionality not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a devexpress grid in which i have provided a cancel button on each row.
I want to show a conform dialog box before he cancels the request.

**Error:** 
The request gets cancelled in each case

**My code :**

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {

            if (confirm("You wanna Cancel the Request") == true) {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

**Asp.net**

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="60px" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="">
                <DataItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" OnClick="CancelRequest" runat="server" OnClientClick="myFunction()" CommandArgument="<%# Container.KeyValue.ToString()%>" CommandName="cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>

                </DataItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Comment: I do not wish to run the server side code if the user presses cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple enough

**Change**   OnClientClick="myFunction()"

**to this**  OnClientClick="return myFunction()"

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="60px" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="">
                <DataItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" OnClick="CancelRequest" runat="server" OnClientClick="return myFunction()" CommandArgument="<%# Container.KeyValue.ToString()%>" CommandName="cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>

                </DataItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete?")) {
   return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Also change minor text in

```
 OnClientClick="return myFunction();"
```